# Serialize is reached before server response is complete

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

In my ember app, I have a router with nested resources, like so:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('explore', function() {
    this.resource('building', { path: 'building/:slug' });
    this.resource('country', { path: ':slug' }, function() {
        this.resource('state', {path: ':slug' });
    });
  });
});

App.CountryRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.SlugRouter, {
  setupController: function(controller, country) {
    controller.set('title', 'country detail');
    controller.set('model', country);
  }
});

App.SlugRouter = Ember.Mixin.create({
    serialize: function(model, params) {
        var name, object;
        object = {};
        name = params[0];
        object[name] = model.get('slug');
        return object;
    }
});

App.Building = DS.Model.extend({
    country: DS.belongsTo('App.Country'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    slug: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Country = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  slug: DS.attr('string'),
  buildings: DS.hasMany('App.Building'),
  states: DS.hasMany('App.State')
});
```

Loading the explore route shows a list of buildings received from the server (a django-rest-framework app), each building has a relationship to a country with a belongsTo attribute.

In the explore.index route, I display the list of the buildings, with links to the country route for each building, using `{{linkTo this.country}}`. The href, however, is loaded as `#/explore/undefined`, instead of `#/explore/<country-name>`.

The part that is confusing me is that this only happens the first time that I load the list. If I go to another route, then come back to `#/explore`, the links render correctly.

In the debugger, putting a breakpoint in the serialize method, I see that the first time that I load the page, the model object is empty (_data.attributes is an empty object). Going to the network tab in the debugger, I see that the a request has been made to the server to get the country data, but the response has not been received yet:

[image: server response not received yet]

The response is eventually received, since `{{this.country.name}}` renders correctly, but after it's too late.

Thanks in advance for any responses/tips.

I am using: 
Ember: 1.0.0-rc.5, 
Handlebars: 1.0.0-rc.4, 
jQuery: 1.8.3, 
ember-data: 0.13,
ember-data-django-rest-adapter: 0.13

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are mixing in `App.SlugRouter` before it's definition. You should be seeing an error like `Assertion failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined]` in the console.

After that you need to load the model for a country by the slug. I don't see this in your Route either. You need something like this in `CountryRoute` depending on your persistence library.

```
model: function(params) {
  return App.Country.find({slug: params.slug});
}
```

I suspect the part that is working right now is because your index route is loading the model and passing it in to `setupController` with the `linkTo`. Direct loading of the nested page requires configuring that route's model hook.

Comment: 2 things: doesn't using `controller.set('model', country);` on the `CountryRoute.setupController` already set the model?

Also, according to the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model), the hook is not called when using linkTo. 

Thanks for the response though!

Comment: 1. When you are directly on the `:slug` route you are on a fresh page with no previous routes and hence no previous models have loaded. Hence the need for the model hook. 2. Correct, the hook is only for the direct route case, with `linkTo` you are passing in the model as an argument.

Comment: The suggested solution doesn't solve the problem: defining the model exactly as suggested in the `CountryRoute`, and commenting out  `controller.set('model', country);` still results in the same error.